# Namespaced models causing UndefinedTable error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have following namespaced models:

```
# app/models/face_data/pool_membership.rb
class FaceData::PoolMembership < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'face_data_pool_memberships'

  belongs_to :pool, class_name: 'FaceData::Pool'
  belongs_to :photo
end

# app/models/face_data/pool.rb
class FaceData::Pool < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'face_data_pools'
end

# app/models/photo.rb
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pool_memberships, class_name: 'FaceData::PoolMembership'
  has_many :pools, through: :pool_memberships, class_name: 'FaceData::Pool'
end
```

And database schema as following:

```
# db/schema.rb
create_table "face_data_pool_memberships", force: true do |t|
  # omitted
end

create_table "face_data_pools", force: true do |t|
  # omitted
end
```

The app is running fine  but when booting (server, rake task etc.) I get the following error:

```
 PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "pool_memberships" does not exist
 LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"pool_memberships"'::regc...
 ^
 :               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
 pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
 FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
 ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
 WHERE a.attrelid = '"pool_memberships"'::regclass
 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
 ORDER BY a.attnum
```

It happens only in production (not in development environment) and looks like it does not have an effect in the runtime (app continues running fine - generated queries use correct table name).

Note that there are other `FaceData` namespaced modules and classes in the app. Setting `table_name_prefix` explicitly to an empty string does not make the error disappear.

My guess is that it has something to do with loading order of files or the `has_many :through` association. Any tips?

Answer (score 11):

To avoid all these problem you can do one thing. Create a `app/models/face_data.rb` with these contents

```
    module FaceData
      def self.table_name_prefix
        'face_data_'
      end
    end
```

With this, you are no more required to write `self.table_name` for each and every class you define within the same scope. In case you have any doubt do let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Another cause of this error is when your application name is the same as a namespace you use for your models.

In a Rails 4 app, you should just need to update your `/config/application.rb` file to rename the module defined there, eg `module FaceData`.

In Rails 3 apps, I believe you will also need to update the routes file too.